# Generalizations of elliptic chain complexes

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, dg.differential-geometry, elliptic-pde, d-modules, chain-complexes

I would like to know if it is possible to generalize the notion of elliptic chain complex of differential operators to different contexts, whether geometric or non geometric. I have in mind D-geometry. For example, in [these](http://www.math.utah.edu/%7Emilicic/Eprints/dmodules.pdf) notes about D-modules, it is given the definition of symbol of a differential operator, but I do not see any analogue of the concept of elliptic operator and elliptic chain complex. There is also the notion of [Hilbert Complex](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/002212369290147B?via%3Dihub), a more general theory that implies some results about elliptic chain complexes. A good answer might also comment on the existence or not of analogue results in these new contexts.

Comment: I haven't looked at what these specific notes say, but D-modules are just a language to talk about linear differential equations, unless you are outside ordinary geometry and work in positive characteristic or something. It's not hard to complete the dictionary (D-module <-> PDE, D-module morphism <-> diff.op.) to define elliptic complexes. You can also consider complexes of diff.ops. that are not elliptic, etc. As such your question is a bit vague.

Comment: It is true that the question is vague as I am looking for constructions that share properties with elliptic operators. I am indeed interested in what is outside ordinary geometry and positive characteristic although not exclusively. I am looking for existing generalizations of some of the conventional ideas to non-conventional geometry or things like graphs or combinatorics. I hope this make it less vague.